# pgfplots: wrong domain, wrong axis, uncentered graph... is it a bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

### Question

I get a very strange graph with `pgfplots`, see the picture below.

What is going wrong?

### Code and picture

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line = middle, 
axis y line = middle, 
xmin = -1, 
xmax = 1,  
grid = major, 
clip = false]
\addplot[color=orange, smooth, ultra thick] {sin(deg(x))} node[right] {$\sin$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `clip=true` solve this.

Comment: Thanks! But, what if I want `clip=false`, for other reasons? (see my updated code, with the label "sin" next to to the curve).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `clip=false` you turn off the clever trimming mechanism of pgfplots. By default, the domain is larger than `-1:1` hence you get the extra drawing (<strike>I think it's `-6:6`</strike> it's `-5:5` by default). So you have to adjust the domain too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line = middle, 
axis y line = middle, 
xmin = -1, 
xmax = 1,  
grid = major,
domain=-1:1,
clip = false]
\addplot[orange, smooth, ultra thick] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Default is `-5:5` FYI; otherwise a great explanation! `:-)`

Comment: @PaulGessler Oh right. Too much pie thinking :)